# Android Studio Error: Activity must extend android.app.activity

Tags: java, android

I am making a relatively simple app for a school project. This is my first time working with android studio btw.
The purpose of the app is to be able to draw inside of a given area, the code for the drawing part I copied from here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views
I'm pretty sure that android studio converted the code into kotlin when I pasted it in, but I might be wrong about that.

The error is showing up in my androidmanifest, in the line '<activity android:name"com.example.colourkiller.Drawactivity". The "com.example.colourkiller.Drawactivity" is marked in red, and the error says: "Drawactivity must extend android.app.activity" and "This class should provide a default instructor"

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.colourkiller">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ColourKiller">
        <activity android:name="com.example.colourkiller.DrawActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.colourkiller

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View


public class DrawActivity(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
    // setup initial color
    private val paintColor = Color.BLACK

    // defines paint and canvas
    private var drawPaint: Paint? = null

    // stores next circle
    private val path = Path()
    private fun setupPaint() {
        // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
        drawPaint = Paint()
        drawPaint!!.color = paintColor
        drawPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
        drawPaint!!.strokeWidth = 5f
        drawPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        drawPaint!!.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        drawPaint!!.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint!!)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val pointX = event.x
        val pointY = event.y
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY)
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> path.lineTo(pointX, pointY)
            else -> return false
        }
        // Force a view to draw again
        postInvalidate()
        return true
    }

    init {
        isFocusable = true
        isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        setupPaint()
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml (layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".DrawActivity" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <com.example.colourkiller.DrawActivity
            android:id="@+id/simpleDrawingView1"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="583dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="79dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D3CACA"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        android:textColorHighlight="#930F0F"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="#A6A3A3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Saved"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
        android:text="@string/saved"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Colours"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
        android:text="@string/Colours"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.946"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/KILL"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/KILL"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:iconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#A6A3A3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A6A3A3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A6A3A3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've already tried:

1. Updating everything to the latest versions
2. Rebuilding the project
3. Invalidate Cashes/restart

I think the problem is in the defining of the class in MainActivity, but as this is my first time using androidstudio I'm not too sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As the error says `DrawActivity` is not an activity you have it extending a `View`

Comment: Ah right, I see. So how should I formulate that then? Excuse my inexperience, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MainActivity` class which extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    } 
}
```

And `Manifest.xml`, modify `DrawActivity` to `MainActivity`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.colourkiller.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Above is an outline. There can be more modifications to solve your problem.

For your DrawActivity is actually a View as @tyczj suggested, you should rename it like DrawView.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a few hours too much trying to solve this on my own... I ran it and everything works now, great!